# CAEmitterLayer negative beginTime possible?

Tags: ios, core-animation, caemitterlayer

I'm trying to get `CAEmitterLayer`s and `CAEmitterCell`s to start their animation from somewhere in the middle of their parent's duration. Is this possible at all? I tried playing with the `beginTime` and `timeOffset` properties but I can't seem to get this working.

Added some code for posterity: (lets say I want the emitter to start at the 5th second)

```
    CAEmitterLayer *emitter = [CAEmitterLayer new];
    // emitter.beginTime = -5.0f; // I tried this
    // emitter.timeOffset = 5.0f; // I also tried this, with beginTime = 0.0, and with beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
    /* set some other CAEmitterLayer properties */

    CAEmitterCell *cell = [CAEmitterCell new];
    // cell.beginTime = -5.0f; // Then I saw that CAEmitterCell implements CAMediaTiming protocol so I tried this
    // cell.timeOffset = 5.0f; // and this
    /* set some other CAEmitterCell properties */

    emitter.emitterCells = @[cell];
    [viewLayer addSubLayer:emitter];
```

But still the animation starts from where the emitter generates the particles.

Edited again to explain what I'm trying to do:

Lets say I have a `CAEmitterLayer` that animates rain, so I setup the cells to do a "falling" animation that starts from the top of the screen. During the start of rendering, I don't want to start in a state that's "not raining yet". I want to start where the screen is already covered with rain.

Comment: Can you provide some code, especially for the part where you set the offset and beginTime?

Comment: I edited my post to include the basic structure of my code. It's very basic setup.

Answer (score 2):

The `beginTime` isn't relative to now. You need to grab the current time relative to the current layer time space, which you can get by using the `CACurrentMediaTime()` function. So in your case, you'd do something like this:

```
emitter.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 5.f;
```

Comment: To be honest, my superLayer is a `AVSynchronizedLayer` so my timing runs with an `AVPlayerLayer`, not `CACurrentMediaTime()`. But, I did try your method with a raw `UIView.layer` but it still doesn't behave the way I expect it to. I'm starting to think that emitters only handle timing that runs forward, not backward.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I explained it wrong. I don't want the emitter to start AFTER 5 seconds. I want the emitter to run 5 seconds EARLIER than the parent timing. I edited the question to include an example of what I want to do.

Comment: @erurainon: If I follow your question correctly, you want to have a negative offset, which really isn't possible, for obvious reasons. :) However, can't you just offset the parent instead?

Comment: I tried that too, but to no effect. Theoretically, a positive `timeOffset` should be the one to do what I'm expecting, but it doesn't seem that way...

Comment: @erurainon: I guess I don't understand why you can't just set the emitter's beginTime to be 5 seconds later. Maybe I'm just not getting what you're trying to do.

Comment: If I set the beginTime to 5, the rain won't start to fall until 5 seconds after. My objective is the opposite. I want the rain to start 5 seconds ahead.